# Access Datatables recordsFiltered field?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have such a jquery request:

```
        jQuery(function() 
                {   
                    jQuery('#numberList').dataTable({

                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax": "${baseURL}voip/provisioning/ajax/dtsearch/" + addType,
                        "columns": [
                                    { "data": "number" },
                                    { "data": "type" },
                                    { "data": "targetDisplay" },
                                    { "data": "lastChanged" },
                                    { "data": "triple9Data" },
                                    { "data": "portingIn" },
                                    { "data": "edit" }
                                ],
                        "columnDefs": [
                                       {
                                           "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                                row.edit = '<input id="numberCheckbox' + row.id + '" type="checkbox" name="number" value="' + row.id + '"/>';
                                                return data;
                                           },
                                           "targets": 0
                                       },
                                ]
                    });

                    jQuery("#list_filter label input").attr("placeholder", "search...");

                });
```

I need to access.

```
$("#pager_total").text(recordsFiltered);
```

on every JSON return. but I could not access:

```
recordsFiltered
```

how to access it?

```
$("#pager_total").text(data.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
$('#some_table').DataTable({
    // your regular call... ,
    drawCallback: function() {
        var api = this.api();
        var num_rows = api.page.info().recordsTotal;
        var records_displayed = api.page.info().recordsDisplay;
        // now do something with those variables
    }
});
```

That returns 16784 in my case which is the total number of records I'm searching through.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting `recordsFiltered` or `recordsTotal` is by acceding to the last JSON response:

```js
var countBeforeFiltering = table.ajax.json().recordsTotal;
var countAfterFiltering = table.ajax.json().recordsFiltered;
```